# Реализация программы перевода числа в текст

Tags: ассемблер

Как можно распознать сотни, десятки, единицы, чтобы при вводе `128 ...` получить `Сто двадцать восемь`?

P.S. В ассемблере новичок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно алгоритм чтения числа выглядит так. Изначально кладём в регистр 0. Читаем символ, если это цифра (коды от h30 до h39: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII ), то умножаем регистр на 10 и прибавляем эту цифру (её можно получить, вычтя h30 из кода символа). И так делаем в цикле, пока все цифры на входе не кончатся.